# Fastlane + Crashlytics Beta release notes not working

Tags: fastlane, crashlytics-beta

I've followed the instructions from the fastlane documentation (https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/beta-deployment/) to add release notes, generated from my Git commits, to my beta deployments.

However, the release notes are always blank in the fabric.io dashboard.

Here is my fastfile:

```
default_platform(:android)

platform :android do
  desc "Runs all the tests"
  lane :unit_tests do
    gradle(task: "test")
  end

  desc "Submit a new Beta Build to Crashlytics Beta"
  lane :deploy_to_crashlytics do
    gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease")
    changelog_from_git_commits
    crashlytics(
      api_token: ENV["CRASHLYTICS_API_TOKEN"],
      build_secret: ENV["CRASHLYTICS_BUILD_SECRET"],
      groups: 'beta-testers'
    )

    # sh "your_script.sh"
    # You can also use other beta testing services here
  end

  desc "Deploy a new version to the Google Play"
  lane :deploy_to_play_store do
    gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease")
    upload_to_play_store
  end
end
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: Follow the instruction in fastlane documentation, I think you have not set the `notes` for `crashlytics` command. Please try to add `notes` under the `groups` line.

Answer (score 0):

changelog_from_git_commits by default fetches the the commits since the last tag. If you don't have any tags, then it will be empty. Look at the options for [changelog_from_git_commits](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/changelog_from_git_commits/) and you'll see you can fetch the last X number of commits, for example.